# Точка входа в несколько .dll библиотек не найдена

Tags: qt, dll, qtcreator

После переустановки Qt creator начали возникать следующие ошибки при запуске любой программы:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Добавление этих библиотек приводит к появлению таких же ошибок, но по отношению к иным библиотекам.

Comment: А что у Вас там в Управление/Комплекты? Все пути указаны?

Comment: @eugesh сложно сказать. Указаны 10 обнаруженных комплектов (справа от четырёх восклицательный знак в жёлтом треугольнике) и один особый.

Comment: Восклицательный знак говорит о неполноте комплекта. Нужно навести курсором и посмотреть всплывающую подсказку. Затем настроить по возможности. Или просто удалить эти комплекты, чтобы не путались.